# Prove continuity of $a(u,v)$ when applying Lax-Milgram theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm trying to solve a Lax-Milgram exercise while studying for an exam. The exercise says:

> Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ a domain and $f\in L^2(\Omega)$. Prove that: $$\mathcal{F}(u)=\int_\Omega ((\partial_xu)^2+\partial_xu\partial_yu+(\partial_yu)^2+4u^2)dxdy+\int_\Omega ufdxdy,$$ defined in $H^1(\Omega)$, has an unique local minimum.

To apply Lax-Milgram, I let $$a(u,v)=\int_\Omega (2\nabla u\nabla v+ 8uv+ \partial_xu\partial_yv+ \partial_xv\partial_yu)dxdy$$ and $$f(u)=-\int_\Omega ufdxdy.$$ That way, $\mathcal{F}(u)=\frac{1}{2}a(u,u)-f(u)$ and, by proving that $a$ is bilineal, continuous, coercive and symmetric and that $f$ is lineal and continuous, by the Lax-Milgram theorem, $\mathcal{F}$ has an unique local minimun.

I have the rest of the hypothesis proven, but the problem is with proving $a$'s continuity. My approach has been trying to prove that $|a(u,v)|\leq\alpha\|u\|_{H^1}\|v\|_{H^1}$, but I haven't been able to do it. Any hints about how to prove the continuity for $a$ and similar bilineal forms?

Comment: To prove continuity of $a$, you have to prove $|a(u,v)| \le \alpha \|u\|_{H^1} \|v\|_{H^1}$, i.e., estimate against the full norm. Does $|\cdot|_{H^1}$ denotes the semi-norm?

Comment: @gerw No, sorry, it was just a typo, fixed now

Comment: It is basically just Cauchy-Schwarz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
$$a(u,v)= 2\int_\Omega u_xv_x+2\int_\Omega u_yv_y+ 8\int_\Omega uv+ \int_\Omega u_x v_y+ \int_\Omega v_xu_y$$
So, it is enough to prove that the norm of each integral is bounded by $C\|u\|_{H^1}\|v\|_{H^1}$, for some constant $C$ (not necessarily the same constant for all integrals). This estimate follows from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. For example, for the first integral we have:

$$\left|2\int_\Omega u_xv_x\right|=2|(u_x,v_x)_{L^2}|\leq 2\|u_x\|_{L^2}\|v_x\|_{L^2}\leq 2\|u\|_{H^1}\|v\|_{H^1}.$$

For the other integrals, the calculation is pretty much similar.